# Looking for alternative security testing tool like Acunetix?

Tags: tools, security-testing

Is there any tool similar like [Acunetix](http://www.acunetix.com/)?, because it's really "user-friendly" for me, and I haven't found something similar yet, preferable with a cheaper price.

So what I like from Acunetix is clear descriptions about *vulnerabilities*, *affected items*, *impact of the vulnerability* and *how to fix this vulnerability*, also the *tool explorer* and *export scan*.

Comment: Have you checked Subgrahp Vega? https://subgraph.com/vega/

Comment: Yes, it's quite similar, does Vega have "Export Scan" feature?, I can't find one...

Comment: What do you mean by "Export Scan" feature?

Comment: To export/save all of the scan result

Comment: No it doesn't have that... You will have to save the results manually... We can get only so much for free I guess!

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to find security vulnerabilities in web applications, you should look at the OWASP Zed Attack Proxy Project at www.owasp.org. The project is open-source so it fits your price range. It runs on Java so it's cross-platform. It provides automated scanners as well as tools for manually locating security holes. It is mature, well-documented and supported. You can find it here: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Zed_Attack_Proxy_Project

Answer (score 0):

There are open source and free (as in beer) versions of vulnerability scanners.  Some of which will perform similar tests to Acunetix.  Some of which will only have a subset of those tests.

Many of them, however, are not bundled up as nicely and won't provide the snazzy features/interface Acunetix does.  The two primary ones I can think of are Vega, which has already been mentioned, and OpenVAS.  Both will perform similar types of tests against your endpoints, but neither will have that full functionality.

As Jerry Penner noted, ZAP can do some of this as well, though it requires manual configuration and supplying many of the non-generic test cases yourself.  Burp PRO (which is what ZAP emulates) costs about $300 a year for a license, and is well maintained and has several built in tools that update regularly.  I am a big fan of Burp and use it almost daily.

https://portswigger.net/burp/editions.html